# Wear App doesn't work if the phone App isn't running or the the phone is locked

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm working on an android wear app that exchanges some information (using the Wearable Data Layer API) with a another android app installed in the phone device .

But if the Phone app is not running or the phone is locked the information cant be exchanged.

Basically I don't wont to look to my phone when I'm using my wearable device(Smartwatch).

any solutions ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You will basically need to implement a [WearableListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService). You can find more on the section **With a WearableService** [here.](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html)

This will spin up a service on the Android device to which you can communicate to.
Don't forget to add the permission in the AndroidManifest.

```
<service android:name=".DataLayerListenerService">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Btw a handy library that gets away a lot of the boilerplate is [Courier](https://github.com/denley/courier)

Comment: Thank you @tim , the Phone App is actually a Cordova App and as I now, we can't implement a Cordova plugin witch contains a WearableListenerService that works on the background .
any other ideas ?